# getting information from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

Please tell me what should be the datatype of reader variable?

```
  public Patient GetPatientInfo(string ID)
  {
      const string sql_get_patient_info = "Select * from dbo.Tb_Patient WHERE id=@ID";
      Patient _p = new Patient();

      DbCommand readCommand = _db.GetSqlStringCommand(sql_get_patient_info);
      SqlDataReader reader = readCommand.ExecuteReader();

      while (reader.Read())
      {
           _p.PatientName = reader["Name"].ToString();
          _p.PatientDate = reader["Date"];
          _p.PatientGender = reader["Gender"].ToString();
          _p.PatientAge = reader["Age"].ToString();
          _p.PatientContact = reader["Contact"].ToString();
          _p.PatientOccupation = reader["Occupation"].ToString();
      }
      return _p;
  }
```

Comment: I believe you can use: IDataReader reader = readCommand.ExecuteReader();

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the DbCommand class then you call

```
DbDataReader reader = readCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader();
```

[MSDN ExecuteDbDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executedbdatareader.aspx)

Comment: please also tell me whats wrong with _p.PatientDate = reader["Date"]; statement?

Comment: as PatientDate has DateTime datatype and also Date Column has.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.DateTime'.

Comment: @SidraAbbasi maybe you need to use DateTime.Parse()?

Comment: but reader["Data"] returns an object and there is no direct conversion between an object and a DateTime. Because you are sure that the object is Always a date and it is never null then call `Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Data"]);`

Comment: @Daniil DateTime.Parse expects a string not an object that is a date.

Comment: You are very young to the site. You need to wait till the site allows you to accept the answer.

Comment: While waiting some reading material http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47448/allow-me-to-accept-an-answer-immediately